# Explicitly stating the type of vector length for references

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get my head around Rust and I'm being faced with a probably obvious error.

I have found a method which computes the dot product of two vectors and I want to implement it so that I do not need to consume the vectors to do so. Right now it looks like the following:

```
pub fn dot(&u: Vec<f32>, &v: Vec<f32>) -> f32 {
        let len = cmp::min(u.len(), v.len());
        let mut xs = &u[..len];
        let mut ys = &v[..len];

        let mut s = 0.;
        let (mut p0, mut p1, mut p2, mut p3, mut p4, mut p5, mut p6, mut p7) =
            (0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.);

        while xs.len() >= 8 {
            p0 += xs[0] * ys[0];
            p1 += xs[1] * ys[1];
            p2 += xs[2] * ys[2];
            p3 += xs[3] * ys[3];
            p4 += xs[4] * ys[4];
            p5 += xs[5] * ys[5];
            p6 += xs[6] * ys[6];
            p7 += xs[7] * ys[7];

            xs = &xs[8..];
            ys = &ys[8..];
        }
        s += p0 + p4;
        s += p1 + p5;
        s += p2 + p6;
        s += p3 + p7;

        for i in 0..xs.len() {
            s += xs[i] * ys[i];
        }
        s
    }
```

The problem occurs in the first line of the function body: the compiler cannot infer the type of `u.len()` as `u` is a reference.

How can I work around this? Is it possible to explicitly state the type?

Comment: I note that you are using a hand-unrolled version of a dot product, which looks awfully similar to the version [posted by Bluss in the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-zip-two-slices-efficiently/2048/12?u=shepmaster). I'd suggest talking to Bluss and creating a crate to maintain this shared code.

Comment: It is indeed the same. I'm perfectly happy to create a crate and people can look at my source code too - however right now I don't think I'm bringing anything new or special to the table :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem as stated *does not exist*.  The error the above code produces is:

```
<anon>:3:16: 3:18 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::vec::Vec<f32>`,
    found `&_`
(expected struct `collections::vec::Vec`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
<anon>:3     pub fn dot(&u: Vec<f32>, &v: Vec<f32>) -> f32 {
                        ^~
<anon>:3:16: 3:18 help: see the detailed explanation for E0308
```

`&u: Vec<f32>` cannot work; this says that `u` should be bound to the contents of a pointer... which is impossible given the parameter is of type `Vec<f32>`.  I suspect you *meant* to say `u: &Vec<f32>`.

But you shouldn't do that, *either*.  There's effectively no reason to *ever* pass a `&Vec<_>` when you can just pass a `&[_]` instead, which will work for more types.  So what you *really* want is `u: &[f32]`.

Once you fix both arguments, the code compiles with no errors.