# Efficiently pulling an arbitrary slice from a vector

Tags: matrix, rust

This is somewhat related to my post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3vkj6f/implementing_divide_and_conquer_matrix/).

I'm trying to implement matrix multiplication in Rust and I think in order to do this efficiently I need to be able to get the column data from the matrix. This is difficult as I'm storing my matrices in row-major format.

I'm using an unrolled dot product implementation which is detailed in the above [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3vkj6f/implementing_divide_and_conquer_matrix/) and also in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036521/explicitly-stating-the-type-of-vector-length-for-references?noredirect=1#comment55845133_34036521). I want to be able to feed this method the row from one matrix and the column from another.

How can I efficiently select the column data from my matrix? And more generally: how can I select arbitrary data patterns (like in R, matlab, numpy etc.)?

I've tried:

1. Using a strided view and collecting the iterator - this seems too slow.
2. Using standard for loop iteration but this seems not to be vectorized by the Rust compiler.

Comment: I feel you're missing context. Why, for example, can't you use the strided view directly? Can you transpose the whole (sub?-)matrix first, and deduplicate the effort? What's not being vectorized? - perhaps we can fix that.

Comment: LLVM doesn't necessarily autovectorize a strided loop even if it recognizes one, see http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#scatter-gather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use more clever for loops you get the answer for your question. I mean, you don't have to pull out a column from your matrix if you reorder your for loops. That way, you keep your CPU cache warm.

If your current algorithm looks like this:

```
// traditional multiplication
for i in 0..a_rows {
    for j in 0..b_cols {
        for k in 0..a_cols {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        } 
    }
}
```

You produce a lot of cache misses since b[k][j] doesn't access your data sequentially.

```
for i in 0..a_rows {
    for k in 0..a_cols {
        // Note, that j iterates over a column of B
        for j in 0..b_cols {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        } 
    }
}
```

If you swap the two inner loops you iterate over B's column sequentially and utilize your cache. First, you will access to `b[k][0]`, then `b[k][1]` and so on. If an element is `4` byte, you can access the next `12` elements from the cache directly (as 64 byte is the most common L1 cache line size). The traditional approach doesn't use the cache so efficiently.